# Optimizing vector/matrix operations in C?

Tags: c, math, memory, optimization

I am trying to see if I can optimize math vector (and/or matrix) operations in C as a project. I noticed that, for example, `memcpy` is much faster than a loop because it uses low-level hardware-assisted memory manipulation, but I'm not that familiar with how it works.

Would it be possible to do something like that, but for operations such as adding or multiplying two float arrays together (vs. just copying)?

Comment: If you want the performance and you don't want to get your hands dirty with low-level optimization, use a vector/matrix library.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/853/c-low-level-optimization-tips has some useful tips on profiling, ensuring your data is laid out to take advantage of SSE instructions (assuming they are available on your platform), removing/optimising conditionals, etc. so would be worth a read.

Comment: Did you test performance of loop with full optimizations enabled? A good compiler should be able to generate essentially the same code for a simple loop, as memcpy uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen from your profile that you are dealing with opengl, I written following answer, assuming that you want to deal with linear algebra. In your case there is no way other then;

- loop unrolling
- preventing from indirect indexing
- targeting memory caching
- compiler/linker optimizations

---

You are in the edge of a huge research area. You may search for millions of publications in the literature with "computational linear algebra", "matrix storage schemes", "matrix-vector operations" etc.

There are maybe thousand libraries, tools and utilities that try to optimize these computations.
However a set of low-level library BLAS is accepted as a standard dense matrix library. Lots of dense and sparse vec-vec, mat-vec,mat-mat functionalities built on it. Either single processor or multi processor tools are available.(concurrent and distributed) Even GPU enabled solutions exist already.

Jack Dongarra is one of the leading researchers on this topic. I believe you may find lots of sources by using the keywords given to you, above.

AFAIK, there is no optimizations like memcpy, because it is a builtin functionality. If something like that exists in the literature it would be available in BLAS.

BLAS has several optimizations supplied through compiler/linker for specific operating systems and harwares.(like loop unrolling, caching etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The prefered approach involves using a library somebody has already developed and spent some time tweaking to get better performance.

However, if you're interested in doing this on your own, one of the easiest optimizations involves incrementing pointers, rather than using offset math (what Semih Ozmen refers to below as indirect addressing).  For instance, consider adding two vectors `a` and `b` of length `N` and placing the results in a third vector `c` also of length `N`.  The naïve approach is:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Here the memory location of each array element must be computed as a base memory address plus an offset based upon the index of the targeted array element and the size of the array data elements.  An alternate approach is to use pointers as in:

```
double *ap = a, *bp = b, *cp = c;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i<N; ++i, ++ap, ++bp, ++cp) {
    *cp = *ap + *bp;
}
```

In this case calculating the array element addresses based upon an offset from a base address is eliminated.  This general approach can be used for any of a number of vector and matrix operations including addition and multiplication.

FWIW, C++ iterators, when properly implemented, will generally use approaches like this while hiding the implementation details to make things safer for the programmer.

Comment: for the knowledge of @Sefu, this optimization is done for eliminating "indirect addressing" or "indirect indexing"